# Call Bootstrap4 collapsible without jQuery

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I want to call Bootstrap collapse event without jQuery, and I though it will work with addEventListener, but only works if I call with:

`$(navbarCollapse).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {});`

Is there any way, like

`navbarCollapse.addEventListener('show.bs.collapse', function () {});`

maybe?

```js
var navbarCollapse = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse');
navbarCollapse.addEventListener('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  alert('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="fixed-top">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-dark p-4">
      <h5 class="text-white h4">Collapsed content</h5>
      <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You are already including jQuery and also have to in order to use bootstrap.

Comment: We can say experiment, but actually because Bootstrap 5 is coming soon and I would like to prepare for that by not using jQuery.

Comment: Do you have this `collapse ` class? It shows undefined in your snippet. If that is available then try adding event listener after page loads fully. You may achieve it by widnow.load or try using setTimeOut. Do let me if it works

Comment: Why don't you use data-toggle and data-target ? you are using bootstrap. - watch this example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: I do have `collapse` class. I also tried it after window load and/or setTimeOut, but nothing.
With data-toggle you can't catch event unfortunately. Here is a CodePen page: https://codepen.io/levipadre/pen/OJMyyBq